# Code Example of "obscuring" as per JLS (6.4.2. Obscuring), especially this "local variable or type can obscure a package"

Tags: java

Could you give a few examples (code snippets) of obscuring?

I read the [JLS](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-6.html#jls-6.4.2), but I didn't understand the concept. JLS gives no code examples.

Hiding is between fields of Base and Derived class.

Shadowing is between a field and a local variable.

*Obscuring - between what (?) and what (?)*

SIDELINE: Interesting, JLS says that in case of hiding respective field from parent class is *not inherited*:

> Shadowing is distinct from hiding (§8.3, §8.4.8.2, §8.5, §9.3, §9.5),
>   which applies only to members *which would otherwise be inherited but
>   are **not*** because of a declaration in a subclass. Shadowing is also
>   distinct from obscuring (§6.4.2).

I also know that *class names, method names and field names are all in their different namespaces:*

```
// no problem/conflict with all three x's
class x {
    void x() { System.out.println("all fine"); }
    int x = 7; 
}
```

***EXAMPLES:***

Finally found an [example](https://programming.guide/java/overloading-overriding-shadowing-hiding-obscuring.html) and some [explanation](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/different-name-reusing-techniques-in-java/) of what is claimed to be obscuring (it causes compile error):

```
class C {
    void m() {
        String System = "";
        // Line below won't compile: java.lang.System is obscured 
        // by the local variable  String System = ""
        System.out.println("Hello World");  // error: out can't be resolved          
    }
}
```

> The above situation could be resolved by using the fully qualified
>   name java.lang.System, or by statically importing System.out. *If we
>   happened to also have variables called java and out, neither of these
>   workarounds would work* and it would be impossible to access
>   System.out.println.

Answer (score 5):

Given the explanation in the JLS:

> A simple name may occur in contexts where it may potentially be interpreted as the name of a variable, a type, or a package.

A simple example could be:

```
int String = 0;
String name = "2";

//Will print 0 as per the JLS
//Would fail without the obscured String variable
System.out.println(String);
```

Where the identifier `String` which is a simple name for the class `java.lang.String` can be said to be obscured in the declaration of the `String` local variable.

Answer (score 4):

As the JLS says, obscuring happens between a type and a package, or a local variable and a type. Here's a simple example of the second type of obscuring, where the local variable `a` obscures a class with the same name:

```
class Foo {
    class a {

    }

    int x() {
        int a = 0;
    }
}
```

Comment: Is it OK that  local variable `int a` and inner class 'class a' don't conflict, I mean I can use both class a and variable a without any problem - see snippet: https://pastebin.com/iUs7r4s5 !

Comment: Is this how obscuring is different from hiding and shadowing - in obscuring both obscured and obscuring entities can be used both ???

Answer (score 2):

**Example 1:**  **"*package name* (`java.lang.System`) is obscured by a declaration of a *parameter* or *local variable*" (JLS)**

*Local variable* named `System` obscures *package name* (*"package name" is `java.lang.System`*), which is why `java.lang.System` is not recognized in the line `System.out.println(System.out);`

```
public class ObscuringTest { 

    // static class System { } // nested class named `System`   

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String System; // local var named `System` (breaks convention)      

        System.out.println(System.out); // compile error        
    } 
}
```

**Example 2:**  **"*package name* (java.lang.System) is obscured by a *field* declaration"**  (JLS)

```
public class ObscuringTest { 

    String System; // field named `System` (breaks convention)      

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        // Cannot make a static reference to the non-static 
        // field System
        System.out.println(System.out); // compile error    
    } 
}
```

**Not Obscuring: Shadowing of a *Type* Declaration by *Another Type* Declaration (JLS, like Example 6.4.1-2)**

```
 // also produces same shadowing    
 // class System { } // same-package class named `System`   

public class ObscuringTest { 

     static class System { } // nested class named `System` 

     // also produces same shadowing
     //  class System { } // inner class named `System` 

    public static void main(String[] args) {            

        // clash with java.lang.System, no obscuring !
        System obj = new System();  // ObscuringTest$System                 
    } 
}
```

> **[JLS: 6.4.2.](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-6.html#jls-6.4.2) Obscuring**
>
> A simple name may occur *in contexts where it may potentially be
>   interpreted as the name of a variable, a type, or a package*. In these
>   situations, the rules of §6.5 specify that **a variable will be chosen
>   in preference to a type, and that a type will be chosen in preference
>   to a package.** Thus, it is may sometimes be impossible to refer to a
>   visible type or package declaration via its simple name. We say that
>   such a declaration is obscured.
>
> Obscuring is distinct from shadowing (§6.4.1) and hiding (§8.3,
>   §8.4.8.2, §8.5, §9.3, §9.5).
>
> **Method names cannot obscure or be obscured by other names** (§6.5.7).
>
> **Field names cannot obscure method names**.
>
> **Constant names cannot obscure method names, because they are
>   distinguished syntactically**.

Answer (score 2):

In this example `A` is an obscured name.

```
public class Main{
    static class A{static int i = 2;}
    static Integer A=1;
    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception{
        //System.out.println(A.i); cannot do because A is an integer.
        System.out.println(A); //prints out 1.

    }
}
```

Name resolution will point to the Integer field, and there is no fully qualified name to access the nested class, as in the case of shadowing.

Although new + constructor will reference the type and not the field.

```
System.out.println(new A()); //prints out class
```

We could a hold of the class through reflection.

```
Class<?> c = Class.forName("Main$A");
```

As mentioned in the jls, a decent naming convention should help avoid this issue.